# Prevent element width from shrinking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tooltip with some text, and in order to control the tooltip's position relative to the cursor with CSS, I placed it inside a zero-sized div. Javascript moves the outer div, and the tooltip can be aligned via any of the top/right/left/bottom attributes, depending on which side it should be placed on.

However, this creates a new problem - the tooltip contents now tries to use as little width as possible. I can't disable wordwrap because it needs to fit on mobile screens. Without the outer container, it works perfectly, stretching up to the window edge. Is there a way to ignore the outer container while calculating the line breaks?

From what I can tell, the tooltip no longer 'sees' the body element so it can't know how much it can stretch. However, controlling the tooltip position directly via Javascript is more complicated if I need to align the bottom or right sides - I have to either consider tooltip size (which can change depending on its position), or set bottom/right properties and consider window size.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/03gdomLt/1/
The first tooltip works correctly, while the second one tries to shrink to zero width.

```
.tip-outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

<div class="tip-outer">
    <div class="tooltip">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra feugiat augue, non pretium massa ultricies vel. In hendrerit tellus.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra feugiat augue, non pretium massa ultricies vel. In hendrerit tellus.
</div>
```

Comment: use min-width in css

Comment: @user2181397 I can't - if I make it too small, it will still wrap when it shouldn't; if I make it too wide, it will stretch outside the screen when it could wrap instead. I need it to stretch up to the available width if needed.

Comment: Would you be able to share an example with the JavaScript? It isn't clear from your example here how `tip-outer` and `tooltip` actually relate. It seems like you could just omit `tip-outer` and have JS position `tooltip` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks only parent width shrinks to 0, the tooltip text are still there but are not able to fit on screen. That is because the parent div (`tip-outer`) is having `left:100px` which is forcing tooltip to shift towards right, hence not visible.

Try below css to fix it for small screen. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03gdomLt/2/)

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 400px) {
    .tip-outer .tooltip{
        left: -90px;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that he want to desired behavior, he just want the text to shrink when the absolute positioned element goes to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can or can not work for your case, but positioning the element relative does enable the text to wrap correctly even if it is positioned left top bottom right.

http://jsfiddle.net/03gdomLt/3/

```css
.tip-outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    //white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tip-outer">
    <div class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse accumsan lectus eget egestas fringilla.</div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse accumsan lectus eget egestas fringilla.</div>
```